# question about quantifier in first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

Is this expression a taotology(true in all situation) (∀x dog x -> ∀x(animal x -> dog x))

I tansfer this expression to (¬dog x ∨ (¬animal x ∨ dog x) , the answer is yes.
Because (¬dog x  ∨ dog x)

But I realised that range of universal quantifier of x is not whole expression,
can I replace the second x with y so  (¬dog x ∨ (¬animal y ∨ dog y) which is not taotology.

which one is correct ?(confused about universal quantifier)

Comment: Please, use the $ sign to format properly the formulas.

Comment: See the post: [how-to-move-quantifiers-to-the-front-of-a-formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570551/how-to-move-quantifiers-to-the-front-of-a-formula).

Comment: Please learn to use MathJax at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I don't understand why this got multiple downvotes - it's a reasonable confusion, and I don't think not using MathJax warrants downvotes either.

Comment: See [Resolution (logic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) and  ["skolemization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form) and [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#First-order_term).

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a tautology, and the problem is that your "equivalent" version (which indeed isn't a tautology) isn't in fact equivalent.

The mistake is that you've dropped universal quantifiers: your first equivalent form, converting implications to disjunctions, should be $$\neg\forall x(D(x))\vee\forall x(\neg A(x)\vee D(x))$$ (writing $D$ and $A$ for "dog" and "animal," respectively). Now we can indeed change bound variables, yielding the equivalent $$\neg \forall x(D(x))\vee\forall y(\neg A(y)\vee D(y)),$$ but again this isn't what you've written - note the "$\forall x$" and "$\forall y$."

In general, removing quantifiers from an expression changes the meaning; put another way, *quantifiers have meaning*, and you can't just ignore them.